# Aligning the item to the left in CSS

Tags: html, css, media-queries, display

Hi I want the input box to display on left just below the first div. The way I am doing I have to make use of multiple media queries to align it to left properly for multiple resolution. How can i do it in best way ? or using media queries for different resolution is the only way.
I have commented out the media query I tried for one of the resolutions

```css
.inputPlace {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 33px;
  width: 310px;
  height: 61px;
  color: rgb(4, 30, 67);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  transition: border-color 300ms ease-out 0s, padding-top 100ms ease-out 0s;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 22px;
}

.btn-circle.btn-lg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  border-style: none;
  right: 60px;
  bottom: 1px;
  background-color: green;
  top: 10px;
}

.inputstore {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/* @media screen and (min-width:1800){
        .inputstore {
       position: absolute;
       top: 210px;
       left: 20px;
        }
        } */
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam libero velit, lobortis et laoreet a, gravida et neque. Mauris laoreet efficitur massa, vitae congue turpis aliquet tristique. Ut scelerisque, nibh elementum pellentesque euismod, sapien
    felis ultrices enim, sed convallis massa erat a elit. Aenean tristique ante id mi maximus, non posuere odio fringilla. Mauris fermentum nulla eu ligula pellentesque, nec condimentum urna semper. Aliquam consectetur a tellus et elementum. Aenean felis
    sem, tincidunt id tortor ac, lacinia sodales lorem. Sed malesuada mi eros, ut malesuada diam posuere eget.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam libero velit, lobortis et laoreet a, gravida et neque. Mauris laoreet efficitur massa, vitae congue turpis aliquet tristique. Ut scelerisque, nibh elementum pellentesque euismod, sapien
    felis ultrices enim, sed convallis massa erat a elit. Aenean tristique ante id mi maximus, non posuere odio fringilla. Mauris fermentum nulla eu ligula pellentesque, nec condimentum urna semper. Aliquam consectetur a tellus et elementum. Aenean felis
    sem, tincidunt id tortor ac, lacinia sodales lorem. Sed malesuada mi eros, ut malesuada diam posuere eget.</p>
</div>
<div class="inputstore">
  <div><input type="text" id="storenum" placeholder="Search" class="inputPlace" value="">
    <button onclick="check_number()" type="button" class="btn btn btn-circle btn-lg"> </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam libero velit, lobortis et laoreet a, gravida et neque. Mauris laoreet efficitur massa, vitae congue turpis aliquet tristique. Ut scelerisque, nibh elementum pellentesque euismod, sapien
    felis ultrices enim, sed convallis massa erat a elit. Aenean tristique ante id mi maximus, non posuere odio fringilla. Mauris fermentum nulla eu ligula pellentesque, nec condimentum urna semper. Aliquam consectetur a tellus et elementum. Aenean felis
    sem, tincidunt id tortor ac, lacinia sodales lorem. Sed malesuada mi eros, ut malesuada diam posuere eget.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `justify-content: left;` instead of `center`  on class `inputstore` ?

Comment: I tried that it dint seem to be working as per my requirement. Sorry updated I wanted it below first div not second

Comment: or `justify-content: start` it would work. What do you want to your last div btw?

Comment: @MaxiGui ..It will work if i have to just shift to left in second div. but i wanted it below first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the align use `justify-content: left;` instead of `center` on class `inputstore`
For the order use flex:

```css
* ADDED */
section{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
section > div ~ div{
  order:3;
}
section > div:nth-child(1){
  order:1;
}
section > div.inputstore{
  order:2;
}
```

For order with `display grid`:

```css
section{
  display: grid;
}
section > div.inputstore{
  grid-row-start: 2;
}
```

### DEMO with Flex

```css
.inputPlace {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 33px;
    width: 310px;
    height: 61px;
    color: rgb(4, 30, 67);
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    transition: border-color 300ms ease-out 0s, padding-top 100ms ease-out 0s;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 22px;

}

.btn-circle.btn-lg {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.33;

    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    border-style: none;
    right: 60px;
    bottom: 1px;
    background-color: green;
    top:10px;
}
 .inputstore {
    display: flex;
/*          justify-content: center;*/
    justify-content: left;  /* New */
    align-items: center;
}


/* @media screen and (min-width:1800){
  .inputstore {
  position: absolute;
  top: 210px;
  left: 20px;
  }
} */
        
/* ADDED */
section{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
section > div ~ div{
  order:3;
}
section > div:nth-child(1){
  order:1;
}
section > div.inputstore{
  order:2;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam libero velit, lobortis et laoreet a, gravida et neque. Mauris laoreet efficitur massa, vitae congue turpis aliquet tristique. Ut scelerisque, nibh elementum pellentesque euismod, sapien felis ultrices enim, sed convallis massa erat a elit. Aenean tristique ante id mi maximus, non posuere odio fringilla. Mauris fermentum nulla eu ligula pellentesque, nec condimentum urna semper. Aliquam consectetur a tellus et elementum. Aenean felis sem, tincidunt id tortor ac, lacinia sodales lorem. Sed malesuada mi eros, ut malesuada diam posuere eget.</p></div>
    <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam libero velit, lobortis et laoreet a, gravida et neque. Mauris laoreet efficitur massa, vitae congue turpis aliquet tristique. Ut scelerisque, nibh elementum pellentesque euismod, sapien felis ultrices enim, sed convallis massa erat a elit. Aenean tristique ante id mi maximus, non posuere odio fringilla. Mauris fermentum nulla eu ligula pellentesque, nec condimentum urna semper. Aliquam consectetur a tellus et elementum. Aenean felis sem, tincidunt id tortor ac, lacinia sodales lorem. Sed malesuada mi eros, ut malesuada diam posuere eget.</p></div>
    <div class="inputstore">
        <div><input type="text" id="storenum" placeholder="Search" class="inputPlace" value="">
            <button onclick="check_number()" type="button" class="btn btn btn-circle btn-lg"> </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam libero velit, lobortis et laoreet a, gravida et neque. Mauris laoreet efficitur massa, vitae congue turpis aliquet tristique. Ut scelerisque, nibh elementum pellentesque euismod, sapien felis ultrices enim, sed convallis massa erat a elit. Aenean tristique ante id mi maximus, non posuere odio fringilla. Mauris fermentum nulla eu ligula pellentesque, nec condimentum urna semper. Aliquam consectetur a tellus et elementum. Aenean felis sem, tincidunt id tortor ac, lacinia sodales lorem. Sed malesuada mi eros, ut malesuada diam posuere eget.</p></div>
</section>
```

### DEMO-2 with  `display grid`

```css
.inputPlace {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 33px;
    width: 310px;
    height: 61px;
    color: rgb(4, 30, 67);
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    transition: border-color 300ms ease-out 0s, padding-top 100ms ease-out 0s;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 22px;

}

.btn-circle.btn-lg {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.33;

    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    border-style: none;
    right: 60px;
    bottom: 1px;
    background-color: green;
    top:10px;
}
 .inputstore {
    display: flex;
/*          justify-content: center;*/
    justify-content: left;  /* New */
    align-items: center;
}


/* @media screen and (min-width:1800){
  .inputstore {
  position: absolute;
  top: 210px;
  left: 20px;
  }
} */
        
/* ADDED */
section{
  display: grid;
}
section > div.inputstore{
  grid-row-start: 2;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam libero velit, lobortis et laoreet a, gravida et neque. Mauris laoreet efficitur massa, vitae congue turpis aliquet tristique. Ut scelerisque, nibh elementum pellentesque euismod, sapien felis ultrices enim, sed convallis massa erat a elit. Aenean tristique ante id mi maximus, non posuere odio fringilla. Mauris fermentum nulla eu ligula pellentesque, nec condimentum urna semper. Aliquam consectetur a tellus et elementum. Aenean felis sem, tincidunt id tortor ac, lacinia sodales lorem. Sed malesuada mi eros, ut malesuada diam posuere eget.</p></div>
    <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam libero velit, lobortis et laoreet a, gravida et neque. Mauris laoreet efficitur massa, vitae congue turpis aliquet tristique. Ut scelerisque, nibh elementum pellentesque euismod, sapien felis ultrices enim, sed convallis massa erat a elit. Aenean tristique ante id mi maximus, non posuere odio fringilla. Mauris fermentum nulla eu ligula pellentesque, nec condimentum urna semper. Aliquam consectetur a tellus et elementum. Aenean felis sem, tincidunt id tortor ac, lacinia sodales lorem. Sed malesuada mi eros, ut malesuada diam posuere eget.</p></div>
    <div class="inputstore">
        <div><input type="text" id="storenum" placeholder="Search" class="inputPlace" value="">
            <button onclick="check_number()" type="button" class="btn btn btn-circle btn-lg"> </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam libero velit, lobortis et laoreet a, gravida et neque. Mauris laoreet efficitur massa, vitae congue turpis aliquet tristique. Ut scelerisque, nibh elementum pellentesque euismod, sapien felis ultrices enim, sed convallis massa erat a elit. Aenean tristique ante id mi maximus, non posuere odio fringilla. Mauris fermentum nulla eu ligula pellentesque, nec condimentum urna semper. Aliquam consectetur a tellus et elementum. Aenean felis sem, tincidunt id tortor ac, lacinia sodales lorem. Sed malesuada mi eros, ut malesuada diam posuere eget.</p></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `justify-content: flex-start;` to align the search box on left.

Answering your second question, CSS will apply to all screen resolution if you did not use @media Rule. Which mean you don't have to adjust for every screen resolution because it will automatically be implemented.

Unless and in case you need different styling on different screen resolution, you might refer to my example in the CSS comments.

```css
.inputPlace {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 33px;
  width: 310px;
  height: 61px;
  color: rgb(4, 30, 67);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  transition: border-color 300ms ease-out 0s, padding-top 100ms ease-out 0s;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 22px;
}

.btn-circle.btn-lg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  border-style: none;
  right: 60px;
  bottom: 1px;
  background-color: green;
  top:10px;
}
.inputstore {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
       
/* This is for screen resolution equal and lesser than 768px

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .inputstore {
    background: blue;
  }
}

*/
```

```html
<div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam libero velit, lobortis et laoreet a, gravida et neque. Mauris laoreet efficitur massa, vitae congue turpis aliquet tristique. Ut scelerisque, nibh elementum pellentesque euismod, sapien felis ultrices enim, sed convallis massa erat a elit. Aenean tristique ante id mi maximus, non posuere odio fringilla. Mauris fermentum nulla eu ligula pellentesque, nec condimentum urna semper. Aliquam consectetur a tellus et elementum. Aenean felis sem, tincidunt id tortor ac, lacinia sodales lorem. Sed malesuada mi eros, ut malesuada diam posuere eget.</p></div>
<div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam libero velit, lobortis et laoreet a, gravida et neque. Mauris laoreet efficitur massa, vitae congue turpis aliquet tristique. Ut scelerisque, nibh elementum pellentesque euismod, sapien felis ultrices enim, sed convallis massa erat a elit. Aenean tristique ante id mi maximus, non posuere odio fringilla. Mauris fermentum nulla eu ligula pellentesque, nec condimentum urna semper. Aliquam consectetur a tellus et elementum. Aenean felis sem, tincidunt id tortor ac, lacinia sodales lorem. Sed malesuada mi eros, ut malesuada diam posuere eget.</p></div>
<div class="inputstore">
        <div><input type="text" id="storenum" placeholder="Search" class="inputPlace" value="">
        <button onclick="check_number()" type="button" class="btn btn btn-circle btn-lg"> </button>
        </div>
</div>
<div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam libero velit, lobortis et laoreet a, gravida et neque. Mauris laoreet efficitur massa, vitae congue turpis aliquet tristique. Ut scelerisque, nibh elementum pellentesque euismod, sapien felis ultrices enim, sed convallis massa erat a elit. Aenean tristique ante id mi maximus, non posuere odio fringilla. Mauris fermentum nulla eu ligula pellentesque, nec condimentum urna semper. Aliquam consectetur a tellus et elementum. Aenean felis sem, tincidunt id tortor ac, lacinia sodales lorem. Sed malesuada mi eros, ut malesuada diam posuere eget.</p></div>
```